# wordpress filter comments by post author

Tags: php, wordpress

Currently using a learning management system to sell courses on a wordpress site.

I need to filter the comments based on the instructor of the course, this way the instructors can filter the comments to anwser questions only about their own courses.

This is the current code

```
function custom_comment_columns($columns) {
    $columns['responder_a'] = 'Responder a';
    $columns['autor_post'] = 'Instructor del curso';
    return $columns;
}
add_filter('manage_edit-comments_columns', 'custom_comment_columns');

function custom_comment_column_content($column, $comment_ID) {
    $comment = get_comment($comment_ID);
    $post_id = $comment->comment_post_ID;

    switch ($column) {
        case 'responder_a':
            $post_link = get_permalink($post_id);
            echo 'Respuesta a: <a href="' . $post_link . '">' . get_the_title($post_id) . '</a>';
            break;
        case 'autor_post':
            $post = get_post($post_id);
            $author_id = $post->post_author;
            $author_name = get_the_author_meta('display_name', $author_id);
            echo $author_name;
            break;
    }
}
add_action('manage_comments_custom_column', 'custom_comment_column_content', 10, 2);
```

How can I create a filter for the column $columns['autor_post'] = 'Instructor del curso';

Comment: _"This is the current code"_ - the first part of that appears to add a custom column to a list of comments (not sure if we are talking backend or frontend functionality here to begin with?), and the second part deals with providing the content for that column, for _one_ individual comment at a time. So that means, you can not _filter_ the whole list of comments using that. Most likely you'll need to use a hook like `pre_get_posts`, to manipulate the specific query that fetches the comments to build the list.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to achieve what you are looking for, is to get the comments of a specific post first.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comments

```
$comments = get_comments( array( 'post_id' => $post_id ) );
```

You also need the ID of the author of this post.

```
$author_id = get_post_field( 'post_author', $post_id );
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_field/

Now you check if the current user is the author of the post. If it is the case, you can display the comments.

```
if( get_current_user_id() == $author_id ):
    foreach( $comments as $comment ):
        // display comment
    endforeach;
endif;
```

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_current_user_id/

The result is a list of comments for a specific post, which is only displayed, when the current user is the author of this post.